# Is there an Event "After Search" for NavGrid jqGrid

Tags: events, search, jqgrid

I want to trigger a function after the user search something on my navGrid.

I've found the event loadComplete but that doesn't match with my expectations because I also reload my grid programmatically. Then maybe there is something link to the click... if someone has an idea.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are exist `onSearch` callback (and `jqGridFilterSearch` jQuery event). It trigger `reloadGrid` which finish with `loadComplete` (and `jqGridAfterLoadComplete` jQuery event). You can set some custom option of jqGrid inside of `onSearch` callback (for example, `$(this).jqGrid("getGridParam").searchingStarted = true;`) and to test its value inside of `loadComplete`. At the end of `loadComplete` you should always reset the value of the custom option. In the way you can distinguish reloading of the grid started from Searching Dialog from other reloading.